# Django check to see if field is blank?

Tags: django

I retrieved an object from my database. This object has a foreign key field, with the attribute blank=True. How can I check to see if it was actually left blank?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`blank=True` is just telling the admin site that the field can be left blank.

Unless you set `null=True` as well, your database should complain if you tried to enter a blank value.

If your foreign key field can take null values, it will return None on null, so to check if it was "left blank", you could simply check if the field is `None`.

```
>>>   obj.foreignkeyfield is None
True


if not obj.foreignkeyfield:
    print "This field was left blank"
```

Comment: What's the difference between `is None` and `if not`?

Comment: @hobbes3,  In the case of an FK field, it doesn't really matter. I used an expression to show console output as an example. `is None` is only True if `val == None`, while `if not` simply checks `bool(val) == False`. `bool(0)`, `bool('')` all evaluate to False.