# Django check if any field is blank?

Tags: django, django-models

I there any way to check if any field Null or Empty without checking each and every field. i have seen this [Django check to see if field is blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036819/django-check-to-see-if-field-is-blank). But in this case we have to check each and every field.
if i am wrong please correct me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way around checking all the fields, but you could write some helpers.

```
any_blank_fields = all((field.blank for field in Model._meta.fields))
```

Oh, you're talking about Falsy values, not blank=True. In that case, you really have no choice but to do some loops, or a list comprehension.

```
instance = Model.objects.latest('pk')
all_fields_filled = all((getattr(instance, field.name) for field in
        instance._meta.fields))
```